# Location of adjectives when a verb uses two particles

Tags: grammar

> 私 は 日本語 を 英語 に ちょっとう難し 訳します. だから 辛抱してください.

I recntly enrolled on a japanese site and would like to put on my profile that; it may take me alittle while to translate messages from japanese to english and ask them to please be patient in waiting for a reply.

Saying that it is a alittle bit difficult for me to translate to english.  Therefore please be patient with me.  Seemed like a better way to say it in japanese.  My concern is that it didnt seem appropriate to put the 難し anywhere where does it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say

> something するのは難しい

or

> something するのが難しい

to mean

> it is difficult to do something

To add "for me", you can say "私には". So, as a full sentence you can say

> 私には英語を日本語に訳すのがちょっと難しいです。

Or, you can use a word "苦手(にがて)" like

> 私は英語を日本語に訳すのが苦手です。

which might hint, depending on the context, that you have some emotional barrier about the translation, or that you have an inferior feeling about not being good at translation.

More examples of similar structure:

> It is fun to swim.
> 泳ぐのは楽しい。
>
> It is sad to see him crying.
> 彼が泣いているのを見るのは悲しい。